# How to find a row where col have alphabets,numbers or special characters (except hyphen,apostrophe and space) in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-like

I have to find the name like : Robert@jr23 (There must be Alphabet,Any Special characters or Numbers except hyphen(-),apostrophe (') and Space).

I was doing as below:

```
select * from test where REGEXP_LIKE(trim(NAME_1), '[^- '']')
```

But I am not getting the right results with this.

Need to match:

```
Kevin#123
bob@jr
mike$dr
```

Needs to exclude:

```
Alex-jr
Robert'jr
Brian jr
```

Comment: Please provide more examples of names that match and that don't match.  What is `NAME_1`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Name_1 is col name and I edited the question.

Comment: I think you need `not regex_like`.  Otherwise you are matching strings that contain a valid character, which is all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `not` with a pattern matching the values you want to exclude. Otherwise you are matching strings that contain any character that is not in the exclusion list, which is all of them.

```
select column_value
from   ora_mining_varchar2_nt
       ( 'Kevin#123'
       , 'bob@jr'
       , 'mike$dr'
       , 'Alex-jr'
       , 'Robert''jr'
       , 'Brian jr'
       , 'A!' )
where  1=1
and    not regexp_like(column_value,'[- '']')
and    regexp_like
       (column_value, '([A-Z0-9]+[^A-Z0-9])|([^A-Z0-9]+[A-Z0-9])', 'i') ;
```

Edit: added a `regex_like` condition to ensure that values contain a letter or digit and a 'special character', meaning here a character that is neither a letter, digit or space, `'` or `-`.

Comment: that works but I only get the records where space, apostrophe and Hyphen is not present but how do I get where I have other special characters.

Comment: What other special characters? This matches all the examples you gave. Is the rule that it must also contain some special characters?

Comment: Yes The name must contain some special characters except space, Hyphen and apostrophe.

Comment: You can add another `regex_like` clause with those characters. If you specify your requirement with examples I can add it in.

Comment: What if no specific special characters are defined to take. Basically I need to select a customer name where there must be a special character or numbers (except space, Hyphen and apostrophe)

Comment: Does 'Special Characters' mean 'any printable character except letters, numbers, `-`, `'` and space'?

Comment: Yes Special Characters means any printable character except letters,numbers  -, ' and space'..... But if I use the regex_like condition I didn't get any records.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to replace everything that's valid with `NULL`, and what remains is *invalid*:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Robert@jr23' from dual union all
  3     select 'Kevin#123'   from dual union all
  4     select 'bob@jr'      from dual union all
  5     select 'mike$dr'     from dual union all
  6     select 'Alex-jr'     from dual union all
  7     select 'Robert''jr'  from dual union all
  8     select 'Brian jr'    from dual
  9    )
 10  select col
 11  From test
 12  where regexp_replace(col, '[[:alpha:]]|[[:digit:]]|-|''', null) is not null;

COL
-----------
Robert@jr23
Kevin#123
bob@jr
mike$dr
Brian jr

SQL>
```

---

I'm confused about what you, actually, want to get as a result. Here are some examples which show result of such a regular expression; which IDs do you want to get as a result?

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, 'Robert@jr23' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Kevin#123'   from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'bob@jr'      from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'mike$dr'     from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Alex-jr'     from dual union all
  7     select 6, 'Robert''jr'  from dual union all
  8     select 7, 'Brian jr'    from dual union all
  9     select 8, 'Brian10'     from dual
 10    )
 11  select col,
 12  regexp_replace(col,
 13    '[[:alpha:]]|[[:digit:]]|[[:space:]]|-|''', null) result
 14  from test;

COL         RESULT
----------- ----------
Robert@jr23 @
Kevin#123   #
bob@jr      @
mike$dr     $
Alex-jr
Robert'jr
Brian jr
Brian10

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

One of your comments says:

> select a customer name where there must be a special character or numbers (except space, Hyphen and apostrophe)

which means that numbers and *special characters* should be treated as "equal". If that's so, does this help?

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, 'Robert@jr23' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Kevin#123'   from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'bob@jr'      from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'mike$dr'     from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Alex-jr'     from dual union all
  7     select 6, 'Robert''jr'  from dual union all
  8     select 7, 'Brian jr'    from dual union all
  9     select 8, 'Brian10'     from dual
 10    )
 11  select id, col
 12  from test
 13  where regexp_replace(col, '[[:alpha:]]|[[:space:]]|-|''', '')
 14    is not null;

        ID COL
---------- -----------
         1 Robert@jr23
         2 Kevin#123
         3 bob@jr
         4 mike$dr
         8 Brian10

SQL>
```

Comment: Its not working for me. I need to select a name where I must have alphabets and special characters or numbers (except Hyphen, Space and Apostrophe)

Comment: You mean, opposite of what that query returns? Try `where NOT regexp_replace ...`

Comment: Can you explain me how "regexp_replace(col, '[[:alpha:]]|[[:digit:]]|-|''', null) is not null" is working?

Comment: It replaces letters or digits or hyphens or apostrophes with an empty string, which means that - if COL has anything but mentioned *characters* - those "anything but" characters are the result. So, if such a string is NOT NULL, it means that COL really has something but *letters/digits/hyphens/apostrophes*.

Comment: Okay, but your statement is fetching space and ignoring numbers , suppose  I have 'Brian10', I should select this and If I have 'Brian Jr', I should not select it.

Comment: True - I forgot about space. But, I'm confused now and can't tell what you want to get as a result. I edited my answer and added an example (IDs included) which shows what such a regular expression returns. Which IDs do you want to get as result? Could you name them all, please? For example, "I want to get IDs 1, 5 and 6".

Comment: Sure, I want to get 1,2,3,4 and 8

Comment: Hopefully, I managed to understand the requirement and added another example. Have a look, please.

Comment: further I want to get the special character or number from the name and want to show it as a separate col. eg: Bob@jr , so I want to get '@' in my additional col.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to include all special characters except `space, - and '`

```
SQL> with tbl(name) as (
  2        select 'Kevin#123'          from dual union
  3        select 'bob@jr' from dual union
  4        select 'mike$dr' from dual union
  5        select 'Alex-jr'         from dual union
  6    select 'Brian jr'         from dual union
  7    select 'Brian)jr'         from dual union
  8        select 'Robert''jr'  from dual
  9      )
 10      select *
 11      from tbl
 12      where regexp_like(name, '[^[a-z]|[A-Z]|[:space:]|[:cntrl:]|/]')
 13  and  not regexp_like(name,'[- '']');

NAME
---------
Brian)jr -- see this is included
Kevin#123
bob@jr
mike$dr

SQL>
```

Comment: If I am using your first where clause in my code its giving me names which only have alphabets but I want alphabets with special characters always.

Comment: what is your first where clause is doing? can you explain please?

Comment: I should not get 'Robert' from the below code:                                                           WITH tbl(name) AS
  ( SELECT 'Kevin#123' FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'bob@jr' FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'mike$dr' FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'Alex-jr' FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'Brian jr' FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'Brian)jr' FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'Robert''jr' FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'Robert2jr' FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'Robert' FROM dual
  )
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE regexp_like(name, '[^[a-z]|[A-Z]|[:space:]|[:cntrl:]|/]')
AND NOT regexp_like(name,'[- '']');